# Display current location on a local image/map in Flutter

Tags: image, dictionary, flutter, gps, maps

I am looking for a way to display the users current location on a map stored on the users device (a .jpg file).  The map is to scale.  And I've seen other apps do this I am just clueless on how to accomplish it.

I've found plugins to get the users current location so that part I have but not the map part. I have researched a lot of Flutter map plugins but all I have found use online mapping services. I have not been able to find any info on how to geo code an image and use that as my map. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Seems like flutter_map might work but there is no strait forward example for my use case that I can find.

Here is an example image/map:

[image: Example of image/map]

Comment: most likely you need a `CustomPaint` - it uses a `CustomPainter` where you should override `draw()` method and draw your stuff